# Best Way to Save Editing State in My Ember.js Application

Tags: html, ember.js

I have spent the last few days monkeying with my app, trying to figure out how best to keep track of an editing state within a given controller. Of course, the problem is, multiple of these ObjectControllers exist at one time, and only one can be editing at a given moment. Below is the important code:

**App.js:**

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

//ROUTES
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('tasks', function() {
    this.resource('task', {path: ':task_id'});
  });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('tasks');
  }
});

App.TasksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Task.find();
  }
});

App.TaskRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});

//CONTROLLERS
App.TasksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  isEditing: null,
  editing: false,
  newTask: function() {
    console.log('new task');
  },
  toggleEdit: function(id) {
    this.set('isEditing', id);
    if ($('#collapse' + this.get('isEditing')).hasClass('in')) {
      this.set('editing', false);
      this.set('isEditing', null);
      $('.in').collapse('hide');
    } else {
      this.set('editing', true);
      $('.in').collapse('hide');
      $('#' + 'collapse' + this.get('isEditing')).collapse('toggle');
    }
  }
});

App.TaskController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: 'tasks',
  collapseId: function() {
    return "collapse" + this.get('id');
  }.property('id'),
  collapseHref: function() {
    return  "#collapse" + this.get('id');
  }.property('id'),
});

//VIEWS
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var self = this;
    Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', function() {
      self.$('.navbar').affix({offset: -1000});
    });
  }
});

//HANDLEBARS HELPERS

//STORE DEFINITION
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
    /*DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000'
    })*/
});


//MODELS
App.Task = DS.Model.extend({
  summary: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  start: DS.attr('string'),
  end: DS.attr('string'),
  recurrence: DS.attr('string')
});

//FIXTURE DATA
App.Task.FIXTURES = [{
  id: "q5ji9chrh1hcu05dohvrf4aumc",
  summary: "Test",
  description: null,
  start: "2013-04-01T10:00:00-07:00",
  end: "2013-04-01T11:00:00-07:00",
  recurrence: "FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,WE,TH,FR"
}, {
  id: "mm4m3pq6icbgbl6m49jpdhi8j0",
  summary: "Test 2",
  description: "absafdaerwer",
  start: "2013-04-01",
  end: "2013-04-02",
  recurrence: null
}];
```

**Home.HTML:**

```
<!--TEMPLATES-->

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div class="navbar" data-spy="affix">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="tasks">
  <div class="row-fluid span8 offset2 task-list">
    <div class="space-top"><div>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordion">
      {{partial 'tasks/newTask'}}
      {{#each task in controller}}
        <div class="accordion-group">
          {{render 'task' task}}
        </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="tasks/_newTask">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="new-task-header accordion-heading" {{action newTask on="click"}}>
      <span class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseNew">New Task...</span>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseNew" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="new-task accdion-inner">
        {{#if task.description}}
          <p>{{task.description}}</p>
        {{else}}
          <p>No description</p>
        {{/if}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="task">
  <div class="task">
  {{#linkTo 'task' task}}
    <div class="accordion-heading" {{action toggleEdit task.id on="click"}}>
      <span class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
        {{#if controllers.tasks.editing}}
          editing {{task.summary}}
        {{else}}
          {{task.summary}}
        {{/if}}
      </span>
    </div>
  {{/linkTo}}
  </div>
  <div {{bindAttr id="collapseId"}} class="accordion-body collapse">
    <div class="edit-task accdion-inner">
      {{#if task.description}}
        <p>{{task.description}}</p>
      {{else}}
        <p>No description</p>
      {{/if}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this code, there are not multiple `TaskController`s being created, I believe. Try setting `itemController: 'task'` on the `ArrayController`. (Discussed [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html), and if you're using `1.0.0-rc.2` see mention [here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/03/30/ember-1-0-rc2.html).) That way you can set an `editing` property on that particular task (and reference `tasks` if `need`ed). Does that clear anything up?

Comment: This definitely helps; two follow up questions. 1) My problem is I only want one `task` controller to have `editing` true at any one time. Is there any way to use what you said to make sure that this is always the case? 2) According to the guide [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/), you can access a parent controller from within a child controller using `controllers.` notation, but when I try that, it doesn't work. Am I interpreting it wrong?

Comment: @BradRoss 2 - You can use `controllers.task` in your template, in your controller you'll have to use `this.get('controllers.task')`

Comment: (1) Hm, you can set an `editing` property on the TasksController as well, looking like `this.someProperty('editing');` on which basis you can hide the edit option for all other tasks. Or perhaps closer to what you want is an `editingTask` property set to `this.findProperty('editing')` which you can retrieve and set 'editing' to false in your edit action? Or more simply: on the task do `this.get('controllers.tasks').setEach('editing', false)`. Hope that helps -- not sure if there's a better way